# I want to extract the ID value from this promise return but how?

Tags: reactjs, sharepoint-online, spfx

I need to get the ID of a newly uploaded file to a document library in SharePoint Online, in order to add permissions to it.
Here's the returned data with the arrow pointing to the ID I need:
[image]

Here's the code and the promise chain:

```
this.state.files.forEach( (file, i) => { 
        
  if (file.size <= 10485760) {
  
   var stringId = this.state.Id.toString();
         
sp.web.getFolderByServerRelativeUrl("/mysitepath/").files.add(file.name, file)
   .then(f => {
          
      f.file.getItem().then(async item => {
       const lists = sp.web.lists.getByTitle("MyDocLib");
                         
          item.update({
           JEREF: stringId
             }).then(async (myupdate) => {
                console.log(myupdate); //this is where I get the log from!
                console.log("Metadata update");
                                                   
const ReadroleDefinition = await sp.web.roleDefinitions.getByName("Read").get();

//  await sp.web.lists.getByTitle('MyDocLib')
.items.getById(this.state.JEREF).roleAssignments.add(item, ReadroleDefinition.Id); // This is where I want to add permissions to the newly uploaded file, but can't get the ID!

          });
   });
```

Comment: isn't it just item.Id ?? Take a look at the documentation: https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-JS-Core/wiki/Working-With:-Files#setting-associated-item-values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
myupdate.item["ID"]
```

Test result:
[image]